# OLE error when running test scripts from QC 11.00 locally

Tags: qtp, ole, hp-quality-center

This has been happening some time now and I finally decided to write about it here so you guys can help me out if you could...

In my TEST LAB in QC 11.00 I have created and EXECUTION GRID importing scripts that have been made in UFT 11.51

When I execute them from QC locally (thus choosing localhost as the host) i get an OLE error.

Now the number may vary but the latest one for example is found in the image attached.

Any ideas?

FYI I have copied the tests from another project in QC.

Thanks![image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have full admin rights.

Also, it is a good idea to switch of UAC if you are using a Windows flavour that has this "feature".

So I'd suggest you grant the currently logged-in user full admin rights, and re-try. If that works, you know what's wrong, can remove the admin rights, and incrementally add more granular rights until it works, so ultimately you won't need full admin rights. (I never took the hassle involved and go with admin rights, so I don't know the minimum rights.)

The fact that you are using "run all tests locally" helps, but still requires sufficient rights for all users involved.

Ah, and just to be sure -- turn of the firewall for testing.

Comment: you have a point there but what i did (while I do not think of it as a solution) is uninstall the ALM plugin and leave the 11.50 version on. after days I installed the 11.51 again and it worked